# Hadoop Mapreduce - Eclipse junit error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.stubbing.Answer

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup a `MRUnit` test case for `hadoop mapper` in eclipse.

while trying to run `Junit` from eclipse  gives Caused by:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.stubbing.Answer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing the dependency for Mockito. In case you use Maven, include

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

or download the JAR directly and include it in your project
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar